# Optimizing mysql query - avg with inner join

Tags: mysql, inner-join, average

Query is taking too much time(4 sec), can I optimize this query ? I just want to calculate average, my query is

```
SELECT r.soiling_percentage_per_hour, rf.rain_mm, AVG( r.soiling_percentage_per_hour ) 
AS     av_soil_factor
FROM `report` AS r
INNER JOIN `rain_forcast` AS rf ON ( r.day = rf.datetime )
GROUP BY rf.rain_mm
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

There may be 10000 records, currently I have given limit but it does not affect on execution. time

Comment: add index with the following column to your table also same sequence as in your select statement

Comment: Having r.soiling_percentage_per_hour and AVG(r.soiling_percentage_per_hour) in the select seems illogical. Do you have an index on rain_mm on rain_forcast, and an index on day the report table?

Comment: So how can I calculate average of r.soiling_percentage_per_hour ?